# Missing e-commerce data

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have to debug the following message which I get in google analytics:

```
The data view XY was configured for e-commerce, but no data is transmitted.
```

This is the [site](http://www.botec.de).

As you can see in the source code, the tag manager is implemented properly, and a network analysis shows that data is transmitted, I get status code 200.

[image]

I used the extension "Google Tag Assistant", it showed that everything works fine (go to the site and click on something, then you will get this:)

[image]

As you can see it works. So why do I get this message?

Comment: To really know why the code is not reaching the platform can be by the filter or incorrect object. So check the filter or please share the Hit to identify if you are  sending the hit properly

Comment: Sorry, Im am not understanding the terminology of google analytics, I am a developer and just implemented it to the website. I try to help my marketing to solve this. Where can I find the "Hit" so I can send it to you?

Comment: With data what you provided, is a bit too less to find the issue. In your implementation, you confirm only GTM tag and GA tag which works fine. The issue could be in the way how you configure the GA tag in GTM, is Thank You page configured properly, do you want to implement standard e-commerce or Enhance E-Commerce, are you try to use dataLayers, for proper investigation should get more info. At the moment it looks like that you try to use Enhance E-commerce and you're not tracking any of Enhance E-commerce features, i.e. you're not sending these data to GA.

Comment: On the screenshot1, if you move the scroll down we can see the parameters sent to Google Analytics,  if you want you can hide some sensitive data, but we need to know if there is some parameter missed

Comment: @KemenPaulosPlaza, I changed screenshot1, now everything is shown. You can also go to the site, the link is in the question.

Comment: @Black, sorry the misunderstood, but was the ?collect the important request. Can you add that one

Comment: I think it would be best if you go to the site and look for yourselve, because the screenshot is very big and the text gets small. The site is linked in the question.

Comment: @Black How you configured at least [purchase](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases) dataLayer push? As I said previously, you're not sending any EC data to GA, i.e. product views, add to cart etc., so just wondering, maybe you configured only purchase data?

Comment: @gintsg, we were not configuring a dataLayer in the website. We only added the Google Tag Manager scripts (one in the head and one in the body for the case that the user deactivated scripts). I was following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart)

Answer (score 2):

Could you show us a little bit more what you have setup in GTM? As far as i can see i assume you should be getting pageviews since the beacons are correct:

[image: Hit Builder]

But im also seeing you have some kind of event that wont work cause your Action and Category are undefined and [Analytics says this fields are mandatory](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events?hl=en).

[image: GA event Doc]

[image: Wrong Event]

If you are not even seeing the pageviews you may have your UA-45904794-4 wrong (Or not well configured on GTM) or a filter on Google Analytics that shouldnt be there.

If you have any further questions just ask and i ll edit this and add more information.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your helpful post! Can you tell me which application or website do you used to find this out?

Comment: @Black For debugging the site i used a Chrome extention called "Google Analytics Debugger" and for testing the beacon send i used a tool from google called Hit Builder. https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/

Answer (score 2):

1. You can check that you don't have ecommerce tracking in the container:

[image]

2. Since you do not, you should **disable** it in analytics on the property:

[image]

This warning means that according to the Analytics property settings you intend to track ecommerce data, but you are not sending any.

3. **Or** you can finish setting up ecommerce **and publish** the resulting container. For example, by following [that section](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce) in the quick start guide:

[image: quickstart guide navigation]

Comment: I just checked it, but E-Commere is enabled. Look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNg8A.png)

Comment: @Black exactly. You can either disable it there or actually set it up in the tag manager by following that section of the guide you linked to. You set up half of it and that deserves this warning.

Comment: I can't find any link to a guide, can you send it here please?

Comment: @Black sure, I added it to the answer.